# Connect AP to Fortinet

Tags: networking, fortigate, fortinet

I'm very new to Firewalls. Internet to my servers goes through a Fortinet Firewall. I wanted to add a wifi connection for other users as well, so I connected a NetGear Router as `Access Point` and gets `DHCP` from the firewall. It worked, and users connected to the AP have an internet connection.

[image]

But, I also want to access servers from that router, but the router does not see the servers and can't access any Application that is on those servers.
what should I do to make that. Bellow are the port settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Fortigate blocks all connections, like any real firewall does. You need to add policies to permit wireless users to access the servers.

You could simply allow all wireless users to make any kind of connection to any server, but it's generally better to permit only what is required: ADS/SMB for Windows server, SMTP/IMAP/POP3 for mail server, etc. Note that the specific applications are explicitly off-topic here.

For wireless clients to find the servers by name they'll need access to your internal DNS - either directly per policy or if you use the Fortigate's DNS server by delegation.